# Emulate "read committed" for Java collection during update

Tags: java, collections, transactions

I have a large collection in my program - around 3M objects. During the lifetime of the application, I need to keep this collection up-to-date with incremental updates. I am looking into a way how to emulate "read commited" isolation level from ACID.

To clarify a bit, the collection can have multiple rows belonging to the same entity. When the update is perfomed, all rows of the collection of the same entity must be updated at once, so no other transaction from another thread can read any partial updates. The structue of the collection doesn't allow to swap all records of the same entity as one operation, i.e. the entity's ID is not, for example, a key in a map.

Currently, instead of doing incremental update I perform full reload of the collection, i.e. first, generate new collection for all entities, then swap. Something like this:

```
private volatile Map<...> db = new HashMap<>();
...
void synchronized update() {
    var tmpDb = new HashMap<>();
    // populate tmpDb then swap
    db = tmpDb;
}
```

It works, but it takes too much memory (though, later it's garbage collected, of course).

I know, for example, that [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) has in-memory databases and it has `Transaction support (read committed)` as a feature. I wonder, how it's implemented under the hood. Maybe I can reuse the same approach.

Comment: Why not use H2 instead of re-implementing a DBMS?

Comment: I didn't want to introduce the overhead of serializing/deserializing between H2 format and our application's classes. And it was kinda overkill for our use case. Though, if I don't find any other approach, I will definitely consider H2 as an option.

Comment: The overhead of implementing something like READ_COMMITTED will be even more in my opinion. It would involve adding possibly multiple locks on each row. I think you're better off using H2 or SQLite.

Comment: Isolation between old and new data implies having old and new data at the same time. How could there be any way around that?